# create a list with multiple parameters on a line android

Tags: android, arraylist

I am new to android. I would like to create an array list that contains 4 parameters: name phone number, type of call, data, but i don't know how to do it. Can someone please help me?

Secondly I would like to ask what is the difference between list and listadapter ?

I mean I need something like this. I need to create an array that is going to print in a log file the first element[1]...second and so on. The first element is an array of 4 parameters(name,phone,type,data). => array of objects.!

```
[1] Me 07678333.. MISSED 23.06.2011

[2] JHG 9898.. MISSED 7.04.2012
....
```

Comment: when you say an array list with 3 parameter do u mean an arraylist of arrays or do u intend to make a listview which displays these 3 parameters in one list element?

Comment: i've edited my code. I have the listview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could make for example a class called PhoneCall:

```
class PhoneCall{
     String name;
     String number;
     String type;
     String date;

     PhoneCall(String name, String number, String type, String date)
     {
         this.name = name;
         this.number = number;
         this.type = type;
         this.date = date;
     } 
    //getters and setters here
}
```

and then make arraylist:

```
ArrayList<PhoneCall> list = new ArrayList<PhoneCall>();
```

and add new items to it:

```
list.add(new PhoneCall(name,number,type,date));
```

Answer (score 1):

i believe what you are looking for is called a custom list view. it involves using a list adapter to give a custom layout for your listview. the layout for every single element can be designed using a separate layout xml file and the addded to the list view. you can refer [this](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html) to get an idea.

also a listview is a layout element that is used to display data in a list format while a list adapter is the bridge between the listview and the data that is backed in the list. i hope that solved your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do here is to create a class that wrap all fields you mentions name phone number, type of call, data).
Then , simply create a List ( implement ArrayList for instance), then add objects of the type you has just defined.
Simple and clear, right ?

For your second question, I don't know what you mean by list. You mean ListView in Android or List- a java datatype. So in the context of Android programming, I consider list here is ListView :) 
ListView is a view that contain many 'item' inside. The way you populate data to ListView could be decided by ListAdapter. For more, just refer [ListView Tutorial from Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)